# Where should EntityManager::persist() and EntityManager::flush() be called

Tags: symfony, soa, solid-principles

I'm developing a medium scale application using Symfony2 and Doctrine2. I'm trying to structure my code according to the SOLID principles as much as possible. Now here is the question:
For creating **new** Entities, I use Symfony Forms with proxy objects i.e: I don't bind the form directly to my Entity, but to some other class that will passed to some service which will take the needed action based on the received data, i.e: the proxy class serves as a DTO to that service which I will call the `Handler`. Now considering the `Handler` doesn't have a dependency on the `EntityManager`, where should I do calls to `EntityManager::persist()` and `EntityManager::flush()`? I am usually comfortable with putting `flush` in the controller but I'm not so sure about `persist` since the controller shouldn't assume anything about what the `Handler` does, and maybe `Handler::handle` (the method that the form data is passed to) does more than just persist a new Entity to the database. One Idea is to create some `interfaces` to encapsulate `flush` and `persist` and pass them around, which will act as wrappers around `EntityManager::flush()` and `EntityManager::persist()`, but I'm not so sure about it since `EntityManager::flush()` might create unwanted consequences. So Maybe I should just create an interface around `persist`.
So My question is where and how to make the call to `persist` and `flush`, in order to get the most Solid code? Or am I just overcomplicating things in  my quest of best practices?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a service that will handle tasks upon your entities, to me, the right way is to [inject](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html) EntityManager into your service definition and do persist and flush operation inside it.

Another way to proceed, if you want to keep separate that logic, is to create an [EventSubscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html) and raise a custom event from your "entity service" when you're ready to do persist and flush operations

Comment: Like I said I don't want to couple my service to the whole EntityManager, But I really do like Event based idea.

Comment: @user2268997: I've only mentioned it because, if the purpose of the service is to apply some logic onto objects AND persist them, as persisting and flushing are small operations defined elsewhere, it could be a good compromise: sometimes just to follow a "golden rule" we tend to develop unnecessary solutions

Comment: @user2268997: ps you need the dispatcher instead of entity manager so you'll be forced to inject something at some point ;)

Comment: It's not about how many things you inject.Otherwise you would just inject the service container everywhere and do whatever you want with it. However handling stuff using Events always requires a really organized code base, and lots of documentation. Otherwise the project ends up as tiny bits of spaghetti that's just scattered all over the place, which is actually worse than lots of spaghetti in one place.

Comment: @user2268997: I understand perfectly what you're saying here. BTW my observation is still valid somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

- about `flush`, as it calls the DB, doing it like you already do when needed in your controllers sounds good to me.
- about `presist`, it should be called in your `Handler` when your entity is in a "ready to be flushed" state. A `Persister` interface with only the `persist` method as a dependency of your `Handler`s, and a `DoctrinePersister` implementation injected in them looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

Another option here - you can implement `save()` method in your entity repository class and make persistence there. Inject your entity repository as dependency into your `Handler` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to couple your service and business logic to the EntityManager (good job), SOLID provides a perfect solution to separate it from your database logic.

```
//This class is responsible for business logic.
//It knows nothing about databases
abstract class CancelOrder
{
    //If you need something from the database in your business logic,
    //create a function that returns the object you want.
    //This gets implemented in the inherited class
    abstract protected function getOrderStatusCancelled();

    public function cancel($order)
    {
        $order->setOrderStatus($this->getOrderStatusCancelled());
        $order->setSubmittedTime(new DateTime());
        //and other business logic not involving database operations
    }

}

//This class is responsible for database logic. You can create a new class for any related CRUD operations.
class CancelOrderManager extends CancelOrder
{
    public function __construct($entityManager, $orderStatusRepository)...

    public function getOrderStatusCancelled()
    {
        return $this->orderStatusRepository->findByCode('cancelled');
    }

    public function cancel($order)
    {
        parent::cancel($order);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```